# Round up with negative ndigits

Tags: python

I have the following below code, which works as :

```
num = 191360.789242721
round(num , -3)/1000
>>> 191.0
```

But how I can round UP and get `192.0` ?

Comment: Round up would be `math.ceil(num / 1000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`math.ceil()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) as a ready-made solution or do it manually with a reverse floor division:

```
num = 191360.789242721
num_ceil = -(-num // 1000)  # 192.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
num = 191360.789242721
math.ceil(num/1000)
>>> 192
```